# to get IN a place or to get TO a place

Tags: prepositions

Since ***to get*** can replace ***to arrive*** (e.g., [sense 11 in LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/get): "to arrive somewhere"), do you say "I got **in** Tucson last night" or "I got **to** Tucson last night"?

Comment: Can you cite the dictionary which gives "get" to mean "arrive"

Comment: @JamesK Done.­­

Comment: WordReference.com: to come to a specified place; to arrive; to reach:

Answer (score 1):

It is very rare that I hear native English speakers (of any English speaking country) to use "in" instead of "to" when it comes to directions of movement or destinations and places. "In" is more typically used by non-natives and they take it from their own language, simply translating their usual prepositions into English, which is a well known phenomena to all of us, I believe.

Comment: but you do say "arrive IN Tucson", so I thought that to GET would use the same rule.

Answer (score 0):

*got* is not the best word in this context, but if you insist -

> I got **into** Tucson last night.

would be better. You went from *outside* the city to *inside* the city.
*got to* might be OK but only in informal speech.

When you write "I got in Tucson last night", it seems like you were trying to say:

> I got (something) in Tucson last night.